# PowerShell Get-WmiObject WIN32_VOLUME WHERE clause

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Here is My Issue. What I am trying to achieve is to display only the information where the drive type is 3(which are HardDrives) but that actually has a driveletter :

```
GET-WMIOBJECT WIN32_VOLUME | where { $_.drivetype -eq '3'}| select-object freespace, capacity, drivetype, driveletter
```

Currently it is displaying :

```
                freespace                      capacity                     drivetype driveletter
                ---------                      --------                     --------- -----------
                273465344                     314568704                             3
              58966519808                  128522907648                             3 C:
```

So the first line I don't want. I've tried adding:

```
where { $_.drivetype -eq '3' and $_.driveletter -ne null } and where { $_.drivetype -eq '3'} and {$_.driveletter -ne null }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter out volumes with no drive letter, treat the `DriveLetter` property as a boolean (both `$null` and empty strings are interpreted as `$false`) inside `Where-Object`.

Make sure your use `-and` instead of `and` (notice the dash):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume |Where { $_.drivetype -eq '3' -and $_.driveletter} |Select-Object freespace,capacity,drivetype,driveletter |Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

---

*(I totally misread your question at first, here is the original answer)*:

The output is implicitly piped through `Format-Table` which generates the table headers you see in the output.

You can call `Format-Table` yourself with the `-HideTableHeaders` switch parameter to void them from the output:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume |Where { $_.drivetype -eq '3'} |Select-Object freespace,capacity,drivetype,driveletter |Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually your first answer was what I was looking for.

Comment: @JPLegris Great, you got 2 for the price of 1 then ;)